# django pass id in HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have page that shows a usecase details with edit button that redirects to editing the usecase.

my views.py:

```
def edit_usecase(request, ucid):
    try:
        usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid)
        if request.method == "POST":
            usecase_name = request.POST['usecase_name']
            usecase_description = request.POST['usecase_description']
            usecase_details = Usecase.objects.get(usecase_id=ucid)
            usecase_details.user_name = usecase_name
            usecase_details.user_email = usecase_description
            usecase_details.save()
            if usecase_details:
                messages.success(request, "Usecase Data was updated successfully!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/usecase-details/usecase_details.usecase_id')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/usecase-details/uecase_details.usecase_id')
        return render(request, 'UpdateUsecase.html', {'usecase_details':usecase_details[0]})
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/usecase-details/usecase_details.usecase_id')
```

my url:

```
    path('update-usecase/<str:ucid>', av.edit_usecase),
```

my template:

```
<div class="row  d-flex">
    <div class="col-12 mb-4">
        <div class="card border-light shadow-sm components-section  d-flex ">
            <div class="card-body  d-flex ">
                <div class="row mb-4">                 
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row col-12">
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <h3 class="h3">Edit usecase details:</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <li role="separator" class="dropdown-divider border-black mb-3 ml-3"></li> -->
                        <form action="/update-usecase/{{usecase_details.usecase_id}}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                              <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                <label class="h6" for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Usecase name:</label>
                                    <input value="{{usecase_details.usecase_name}}" type="text" name="usecase_name" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Name of Employee" required>                           
                                </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                <label class="h6" for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">User Name:</label>
                                    <input value="{{usecase_details.usecase_description}}" type="text" name="usecase_description" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Name of Employee" required>                             
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Changes">
                          </form>


                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I pass the usecase id in HttpResponseRedirect to redirect me to the same page after updating the data>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the usecase id like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/usecase-details/{ucid}')
```

or use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) which is the recommended solution:

```
# url
path('update-usecase/<str:ucid>', av.edit_usecase, name="usecase-edit"),

# view
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-edit', args=[ucid]))
```

Comment: What about using this simply `return redirect('usecase-edit', ucid=ucid)`? ;)